# How to Sum First n Occurrences of Numeric Values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

My data range is `L1:L26`, and its values are a mixture of numbers & strings.

`L5`, `L8`, `L11`, `L14`, `L20`, `L23` & `L26` contain numbers. The rest contain strings.

I'm trying to get the sum of the first 3 numeric values. 
These values are 7, 45 & 11, so the result, stored in `M2`, should be 63.

I'm using the following formula:

```
{=Sum(Sum(Offset(L1, Small(If(ISNUMBER (L2:L26), Row(L2:L26)))))}
```

The formula produces an error.

NB: It's an array formula.

Comment: Could you also tag this question (and any others you post) with the version of Excel you are using? Some functions seem to work differently in array formulas in different Excel versions.

Comment: Currently I'm using Excel Version 2016.☺

Answer (score 0):

This new formula definitely* works:

```
{=SUM(L2:INDEX(L:L,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(L2:L26),ROW(L2:L26)),3)))}
```

Just remember, this time it **is** entered as an array formula.

---

Looking at your formula, in addition to the unnecessary second `SUM()` there are four major errors:

1. There is a space between the `R` and `(` in `ISNUMBER ()`;
2. `SMALL()` is missing the required second parameter, `3`;
3. `OFFSET()` is missing the required third parameter, `0`;
4. The second parameter of `OFFSET()`is off by +1 (should be `SMALL()-1`).

And then there's the critical error: `OFFSET()` cannot be made to return an entire array*. It can only be used to fill a range when array-entered in multiple cells.

*At least in Excel 2007

Comment: Sorry Robin your non array formula has generated unexpected answer 212864.7 instead of 63.
And if I'm using it as an array formula the answer is 7.

Comment: @RajeshS Oops! Sorry about that. I tested with `L14`, `L20`, `L23` and `L26` set to 0 (face palm) and since my formula was actually summing *all* the numeric values I was getting the correct result! Updating my answer with a new working formula.

Comment: Finally I've got the solution and with corrections the following Formula is working perfectly.


{=Sum(Sum(Offset(L1, Small(If(ISNUMBER (L2:L26), Row(L2:L26)), {1,2,3})-1,)))}


@Robin if I use only one Sum formula considers only the 1st value. 2nd Sum & -1 manages the occurrence successfully. ☺

Comment: @RajeshS That's why I asked if you could tag which version of Excel you were using. Your solution *doesn't* work in Excel 2007. I suspect both `OFFSET()` and `SUM()` behave differently in 2007 and 2016. Just out of curiosity, does my solution work in Excel 2016?

Comment: ,, no your suggestion doesn't works with 2013 & 2016 also. 

Application software may differ in case of Function especially with VBA Codes. ☺